# Does Windows XP has any compression program by default?

Tags: windows, compression, zip

I would like to compress a database backup file on Windows.

I wonder if Windows XP has by default any program (like WinZip) that I can use.

If yes, where is it located ?

If not, could you suggest a light program that does the task ?

Comment: (But in answer to your question, just right-click and choose "Send To" and choose "Compressed (zipped) folder")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question belongs on superuser.com, however my favorite compression program is 7zip http://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: This is probably not the right site for this type of question. I use 7-zip. Works like a charm. - You just beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, XP includes a compression program.  Right click on the desktop and choose `New` -> `Compressed (zipped) Folder`.  You should be able to copy your database into that new file as if it were a folder.

However, this is pretty basic compression.  You'll do a lot better by downloading something like [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).